# Kendo UI DatePicker in popup

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-template, kendo-datepicker

I want to create a Kendo DatePicker in Kendo template. Here is my Kendo template.

```
    <script id="popup-doc-details" type="text/x-kendo-template">
      <input id="DateTesting" style="width: 180px">
    </script>
```

How can I init Kendo DatePicker. For more info this template is part of a popup and shown when something choose from Kendo  DropDown and DatePicker number will be dynamically changed with providing data. DropDown data is like.

```
    [{name:"test1", tags:[{name:"datename",type:"date"},{name:"datename",type:"date"}]}, {name:"test2", tags:[{name:"datename",type:"date"}]}]
```

Example: If I choose test1 from DropDown, Kendo template will load DatePicker according to tags.

I know I can achieve this using loop in Kendo template. but my question is how can I init Kendo DatePicker dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

You can create datepicker in template using MVVM style like this

```
 <input name="selectedDate" type="date" 
        data-bind="value: selectedDate" 
        data-format="dd MMMM yyyy" 
        data-role="datepicker" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> For Angular2/4:

**HTML**

```
<!-- Calendar Icon -->
<span #anchor (click)="onToggle()" class="k-icon k-i-calendar"></span>

<!-- Kendo Popup with calendar inside -->
<kendo-popup [anchor]="anchor" (anchorViewportLeave)="show = false" *ngIf="show">
    <kendo-calendar class="pointer" [(value)]="examDate" (valueChange)="calendarFunc($event)"></kendo-calendar>
</kendo-popup>
```

**JS/TS**

```
public onToggle(): void {
    this.show = !this.show;        
}
```

I use a show variable to display the popup.

---

> For Jquery / Knockout:

[Popup Info](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/layout/popup/overview)

[Calendar Info](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/calendar/events)

**HTML**

```
<!-- Anchor Position with calendar Icon iside --> 
<div class="datepicker-anchor">
    <span class="k-icon k-i-calendar" data-bind="click: onToggle.bind($data)" ></span>
</div>
<!-- Popup with calendar inside -->
<div id="popup">
    <div id="calendar"></div>
</div>
```

**JS/TS**

```
private popup: any;

constructor() {

    function onChangeCalendar() {
        var date = this.value();
        self.onToggle();           
    }

    $("#calendar").kendoCalendar({
        change: onChangeCalendar            
    });

    this.popup = $("#popup").kendoPopup({
        anchor: $(".datepicker-anchor")
    }).data("kendoPopup");
    this.popup.close();
}

onToggle = (): void => {
    this.show = !this.show;

    if(this.show)
        this.popup.open();
    else
        this.popup.close();
};
```